# Boost interthread communication queue

Tags: c++, boost, parallel-processing, ipc

I'm using Boost::interprocess::message_queue to enable communication between threads on my application. I'm doing so for two reasons. First, because I don't need to directly implement a shared mem. synchronization mechanism and second because I want to model the system this way because in the future it may change to interprocess.

My question is: Is there any more apropriate mechanism to enable interthread communication given this restrictions or I can continue using interprocess queue without fear for 'interprocess overhead'?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `std::queue` protected by a `boost::mutex` & `boost::condition_variable`

Anthony Williams provides an excellent explanation on how to implement a thread safe queue in his book 'C++ Concurrency in Action'.

Example code is available on his website here:

[Just Software Solutions - Implementing a Thread Safe Queue](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html)